# Add user to Active Directory group with start and end date

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, activedirectorymembership, active-directory-group

I'm searching for a solution for **adding a user account to a security group or to a distribution list in Active Directory** but with a **membership start and end date**. We are managing the AD through a 3rd party console called Quest Active Roles console and this can add a user temporary to a security group but i have to do this **from a .NET application**. As i can see the .NET directory services can not do this.

Any idea?

Comment: I don't think there's anything like that available out of the box. My approach would be to (1) add the user to the group on the "start date", and (2) make yourself a note somewhere (possibly in the app itself) to remove him again on the given end date. If you have an automated service that runs around the clock, that service could check a list of users to be removed every night and go about doing that.

Comment: Yes this will be the solution.